# Has anyone successfully installed cygwin/xview/wfdb/ecgpuwave recently? Does it work?

Tags: image-processing

I am having a problem with cygwin/xview/wfdb/wave/ecgpuwave.
Having installed CYGWIN successfully, I installed XVIEW followed by WFDB according to procedure specified at:
http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-windows-quick-start.shtml 
The xview binaries were xview-3.2p1.4-18c-cygwin.tar.bz2 
Everything installs without errors, that is cygwin,xview,wfdb. I can open an xwindow, issue test commands for wave. The only command that fails is "wave -r 100s -a atr &". The error is:

**assertion "ret != inval_id" failed: file "/usr/src/ports/libX11/libX11-1.5.0-1/src/libX11-1.5.0/src/xcb_io.c", line 528, function: _XAllocID**

Comment: I don't see a programming related question. You may want to try SuperUser instead.

Comment: @VenomFangs. Thank you for your answer. If I understand your answer right, you are suggesting the use of another piece of software instead of wfdb/wave/ecgpuwave. If that is the case, I am afraid it is out of the question. It has to be wfdb/wave/ecpuwave. Regards, Geraldine.